# Can I salvage a towbar from an identical donor car?

Tags: vauxhall, towing

I would like a towbar for my 2003 Opel Agila (I am not joking!) and I have seen an Opel Agila advertised at a nearby scrapyard with a towbar. The towbar was an optional factory extra according to the service manual from 2003. I can legally tow with it as towing weights are listed in the Manual, and online in many places. I was considering a new eBay DIY kit, but I am worried that they are firstly poor quality, and apparently the instructions are crap, and I do not want to fit it wrong for obvious reasons!

I also think removing the towbar myself would be a good idea as then I can see how it is fitted back on.

Would there be any (mainly safety) problems with using a second hand towbar and mountings from an identical donor car (2003 Opel Agila) from the local Scrapyard/Breakers?

*Because almost every single one of my recent questions seems to have a British/American English language problem, this is a towbar!*

[image]

I would preferably not want to buy one online unless there is no other choice, as I want to check the quality, and I have had several bad experience with online car parts from eBay and Amazon that either do not fit or work properly.

Comment: Ah, the glorious tow hitch.  the breaker of knees, ankles..  and the cause of many foul words used while walking passed the back of the vehicle.  If you're nervous about Ebay why not cite another location for purchase?  Such as Amazon?  What do the reviews say on the seller?  Is there a warranty?

Comment: If it is from the same year,make and model it will work just fine, try to get all the attaching hardware (bolts,nuts,spacers) also.

Comment: And as long as the car in the scrap yard hasn't been rear ended! ;-)

Comment: You're not buying smashed up stuff, you're making the world by recycling, so things don't end up in the landfill.

Comment: @zipzit Yeah, I know. I love the scrapyard as literally everything is £2, and it's better than new parts as it is literally DIY recycling!

Comment: I will say, I'm hoping there is a whole lot of steel structure behind that rear bumper.  You are going to want all the metal that helps hold up that towing ball.  There should be multiple points of attachment to the body sheet metal of the car.  If its just those two bolts and nothing else, you are not going to have much towing capacity.  A surfboard on a light trailer only.  The towing weights in the manual = the factory towing ball with ALL the hidden structure and supports for that rear bumper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can - but make sure you get all the bits that are needed to attach it to the car. Assuming it's an OEM towbar, the mounting points on the chassis should already be present, but you'll probably need bolts, brackets etc from the donor car. You'll also need the full wiring harness including any internal plugs etc that attach it to the car's wiring loom.

Check it all thoroughly to make sure it's in good condition before fitting it to your car, and if any bolts are too badly corroded, replace them with suitable specification replacements.

It's probably worth taking photos as you remove it, that way you can check how it all goes back together!

Comment: Good note on the wiring harness.  Might want to look at your own before you go so you know what exactly you need to grab.  Depending on what your harness looks like, and what the harness on the tow package car looks like, you might want to grab pig tails to make it easier to wire in place.